# codeigniter - back button after logout still working

Tags: php, codeigniter

created a simple page of session, Even after logout from the page i'm still able to access the login page.
I have also destroyed all the session but still can't find any solution.

**view - flashdata_home.php**

```
<form action='add' method='post'>

     <input type ='text' name='value'/>
     <input type='submit' value='Enter ' />

</form>
```

**Controller - FlashData_Controller.php**

```
<?php

class FlashData_Controller Extends CI_Controller {


    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');

    }

    public function index(){
         $this->load->view('flashdata_home');
    }

    public function add(){
    // adding flash data 
    //$this->session->set_flashdata('item','This is me');

    $this->session->set_userdata('Name',$this->input->post('value'));

    //redirect to home page
    //  redirect('flashdata');

    if($this->session->has_userdata('Name')){

        $data = array('value' => $this->session->Name);
        $this->load->view('adminflashdata_home',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('flashdata_home');
    }
   }

    public function logout(){

        $this->session->unset_userdata('Name');
        $this->session->sess_destroy('Name');
        $this->load->view('flashdata_home');

    }

}
```

**view - adminflashdata_home.php**

```
<?php 
echo $value;
<li><a href="logout">Logout</a></li>
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsettling the session in CI is very simple and it looks like this.

In your Code you have unset the data but you have to unset the variable as i did.

**For Single Data:**

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('some_name');
```

**For Array of Datas:**

```
$array_items = array('username' => '', 'email' => '');
$this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
```

**For destroy the session:**

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, though we destroy session we can still access the page that should be loaded only if the user in logged in.

For example, when user log in with correct credentials the url should look like this: localhost/app/controller/function (just for instance). And later when the user log out you will redirect back to login page. But if we type localhost/app/controller/function in url or if we click back button in browser, the browser will load the page !!! I consider your stated problem is same like this.

For this problem I always use a solution in every function of controller. Like;

```
class MainController extends CI_Controller {
  function test {
    $user_name = $this->session->userdata('user_name');
    if(isset($user_name)) {
      //the actual function code goes here
    }
    else {
      //redirect to the login function
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helped some one.. cheers..

Comment: can you once please check whether session variable are properly set or not? just echo all the session variables once you login..

Comment: Yeah session variable is set. but cant find any solution till now.

Comment: I'm so sorry to hear that, can you please post one of your controller function by implementing the method that I've mentioned above..

Comment: public function logout(){

    //        $this->session->unset_userdata('Name');
    //        $this->session->sess_destroy('Name');
    //       redirect('FlashData_Controller/index');

    unset($_SESSION['Name']);
        if(session_destroy())
        {
           // $this->load->view('flashdata_home');
            redirect('FlashData_Controller/index');
        }
    else 
        {
         echo     $_SESSION['Name']; 
        }
    }

Comment: I have tried both the ways the commented and un commented but still not working. after logout when i press back button i get an information saying Confirm Form Resubmission when i press ok the login page is loaded again